# What is the probability that the contents person A picked are more valuable than the contents person B picked

Tags: probability

Been stuck on this one for a while.

A bag contains ten identically wrapped boxes, but the contents of the boxes have different values (e.g., each contains a different amount of money). Alice and Bob are each going to pick one box from the bag. Suppose Alice picks first (one of the ten boxes at random) and then Bob picks at random from the remaining boxes. What is the probability that the contents of Alice’s box are more valuable than the contents of Bob’s box? Is there an advantage to going first?

Comment: Have you tried to solve a simpler version of this problem?  If each person is allowed to pick only one box, the simplest version involves having only two wrapped boxes in the bag.

Comment: In other words, is the probability that person A wins greater than $1/2$? What have you tried so far?

Comment: If a value is a real number, then the values picked by Alice and Bob are identically distributed random variables, $X_A$ and $X_B$. Students are usually confused by dependency of $X_A$ and $X_B$, but the problem provides no conditional information that could change our opinion about the distribution of $X_A$ or $X_B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going first shouldn't matter, since if no one looks, they could just as easily switch boxes, and they would be indifferent to the switch.

If that argument is not convincing, shown below is a case-based approach . . .

Only the order of the values matters, so we can assume the dollar values are $1,2,3,...,10$.

Then for $1\le a\le 10$, Alice chooses $a$ with probability ${\large{\frac{1}{10}}}$, and for each $a$, Alice wins with probability ${\large{\frac{a-1}{9}}}$, hence the probability that Alice wins the game is
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{a=1}^{10}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\!\left(\frac{a-1}{9}\right)\\[4pt]
=\;&\frac{1}{90}\sum_{a=1}^{10}(a-1)\\[4pt]
=\;&\left(\!\frac{1}{90}\!\right)\!(45)\\[4pt]
=\;&\frac{1}{2}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}